Linux filesystem remapping
I have an ssd drive and a internal HD one. I want OS pointing to the home located in internal HD and working files Downloads, Music, Videos, Templates, Documentos etc., locatein the HD. My /etc/fstab was edited and got this form.
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Mon Jul 1 14:06:56 2024
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=dd0ea175-5e75-4f72-90fc-d07bbda56824 / btrfs subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 0 0
UUID=2f88394b-5363-4372-bec2-4de07e9bf319 /boot ext4 defaults 1 2
UUID=dd0ea175-5e75-4f72-90fc-d07bbda56824 /home btrfs subvol=home,compress=zstd:1 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a2135a6-7123-4a03-94dd-26e7ce663204 /mnt/8a2135a6-7123-4a03-94dd-26e7ce663204 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=8a2135a6-7123-4a03-94dd-26e7ce663204 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
~

~/.config/user-dirs.dirs is configured like this
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
#
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documentos"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Imagens"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"

where $HOME is /home/herlimenezes, located in SSD and not as desired in /mnt/8a2135a6-7123-4a03-94dd-26e7ce663204/herlimenezes
As I issued fdisk -l and got this:
Disk /dev/sda: 223,57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F4B01EB2-AC35-4F88-8EDE-02F3C26E7B17

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1 2048 206847 204800 100M EFI System
/dev/sda2 206848 239615 32768 16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3 239616 467844462 467604847 223G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4 467845120 468858879 1013760 495M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdb: 111,79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 958A1E52-0221-4536-9D15-D07E2A20B448

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdb1 2048 4095 2048 1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2 4096 2101247 2097152 1G Linux extended boot
/dev/sdb3 2101248 234440703 232339456 110,8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000VM002-1ET1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x374a1498

Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1 2048 1953523715 1953521668 931,5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

I hope that this information is relevant to get a solution.

mount the disk somewhere and symlink /home (and ev. other directories) to the location. So it would be transparent, and file are visible also on the expected location. Note: in such manner you may change location/disk in future, without problems. -- Note: not all location of a distribution can be moved (relative symlinks and hard link expectations)

What happens if you just comment out the line beginning with UUID=dd0 and reboot? And what edited /etc/fstab?

I commented on that line, (first one), system felt back to emergency mode, so I edited /etc/fstab, and Fedora is working in the old way.

In fstab you have two mounts on /home UUID=dd0ea175-5e75-4f72-90fc-d07bbda56824 /home btrfs subvol=home,compress=zstd:1 0 0 and UUID=8a2135a6-7123-4a03-94dd-26e7ce663204 /home ext4 defaults 0 2 so I suppose that the second is mounted over the first one. cat you add to your post the output of blkid so we can sort it out ?

Thank you
Here is the output of blkid, as you asked. I posted it in fpaste because it was too long.
https://paste.centos.org/view/61345e07
